# Help finding Star Wars set, 8x8 grey cone with white end

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

Bought a bulk lot of LEGO with no instructions. I have one piece I can't locate the set for - any help would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the one picture that did come through, you have set [9490 - Droid Escape](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=9490-1) from 2012.

[image]